# all php codes in one line

Tags: php, newline

I have to edit a `php code file` from ftp. I downloaded the files on my pc but one of the files is shown like `all the codes in one single line`. As if there is no new line chars after `;`
I use `Netbeans IDE` and i also try to open it in notepad but the context seems the same, no new line chars. So there is a mass text in one single line and the code is not readable. My OS is Windows 8.1.
What is the reason that i can not view the file? Is it corrupted?

Comment: Most likely because your IDE (And specially notepad) don't support `\n`, but rather only `\r\n` (the windows equivilant of a new line). Either change all `\n`'s to `\r\n` or use a decent IDE (I can't believe Netbeans would show it wrong).

Comment: Are you downloading in binary or ascii mode?

Comment: @AbraCadaver i think ascii mode

Comment: Try binary and don't use notepad.

Comment: @h2ooooooo thank you, it seems it is a CR LF problem. Maybe the file created on linux with LF character as a new line, then i try to open it on windows with CR LF chars as a new line. elimirks's phpbeautifier showed the tidy content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may have been compacted/uglified. Try plopping it in a beautifier:

http://phpbeautifier.com/